# Passing Global and Outer Context as an Parameter to Hugo Partial Template

Tags: go, hugo, go-templates

In Hugo, one can pass the current context to a partial template using the `.` as in `{{ partial "page/head" . }}`. My problem is within `with` blocks the context changes depending on the input for the `with` block. In some situation, I want to pass an outer context or the global context to the template.

My question is how do I access and pass the outer or global contexts to partial templates in Hugo templates?

I am new to `go`, `hugo` and `go templates`.